# Python Telegram Bot Queue not Running on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, telegram, python-telegram-bot

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
from telegram import bot, ParseMode
import os
import datetime
import pytz
import logging
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask import Flask
load_dotenv()

TOKEN = os.environ.get('API_KEY')
CHAT_ID = os.environ.get('CHAT_ID')
PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', '8443'))

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def daily_job(update, context):
    """ Running on Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri = tuple(range(5)) """
    sport = datetime.time(15, 12, 10, 000000, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('America/Chicago'))
    trading = datetime.time(15, 13, 10, 000000, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('America/Chicago'))
    forex = datetime.time(15, 14, 10, 000000, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('America/Chicago'))
    print("Time its supposed to post sport", sport)
    print("Time its supposed to post trading", trading)
    print("Time its supposed to post forex", forex)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text='Activating daily notification!')
    context.job_queue.run_daily(purchase_forex(update, context), forex, days=tuple(range(7)), context=update)
    context.job_queue.run_daily(purchase_sports(update, context), sport, days=tuple(range(7)), context=update)
    context.job_queue.run_daily(purchase_trading(update, context), trading, days=tuple(range(7)), context=update)

def purchase_forex(update, context):
    print('running forex')
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text="Daily Forex", parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)

def purchase_sports(update, context):
    print('running sports')
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text="Daily Text", parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)

def purchase_trading(update, context):
    print('running trading')
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text="Daily Trading Text", parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)

def error(update, context):
    """Log Errors caused by Updates."""
    logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)





def main():

    u = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
    u.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', daily_job, pass_job_queue=True))
    u.dispatcher.add_error_handler(error)

    # Start the Bot
    u.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0",
                          port=PORT,
                          url_path=TOKEN,
                          webhook_url="https://<appname>.herokuapp.com/" + TOKEN)


    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    u.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running this code on heroku doesn't give me what I expect

2021-09-28T20:11:36.231963+00:00 app[web.1]: Time its supposed to post forex 15:14:10
2021-09-28T20:11:36.457226+00:00 app[web.1]: running forex

But after this, it doesn't run any of the other functions, and it always posts the forex chat as soon as the /start command is done. Really, I'm looking for a way to get the /start command to run properly and to get that command to run on each reboot so I don't have to keep going back and manually doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first problem: you're using `run_daily` wrong. As explained in the [wiki article](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue) and in the [documentation](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html#telegram.ext.JobQueue.run_daily), the first argument needs to be a function. Instead you pass `purchase_forex(update, context)`, which is the return value of `purchase_forex`, which is `None`. Also the function that you pass must accept exactly one argument, not two. Please make sure to read the wiki article, the documentation and probably also [this example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples#timerbotpy) to better understand how the `JobQueue` works in PTB.

About scheduling the jobs without a need to call the `/start` command: the job queue is available as `u.job_queue` and as `u.dispatcher.job_queue` (both are the same object as `context.job_queue`. so you can do the scheduling right in your `main`.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Thank you so much man, you were 100% right and the documentation you linked helped a lot. I appreciate it.